# iwconfig showing unnecessarily lo and eth interfaces

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I direct `iwconfig` output to file so then I can process it, like:

```
iwconfig > file_name.txt
```

The file contents in my case are:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Some ESSID"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:21   Missed beacon:0
```

Although the message:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

is printed in standard output.

I tried `iwconfig > /dev/null` but then data useful for me is directed into `null` and "annoying" `lo` and `eth0` are still prompting.
I've read some threads about `iwconfig` related problems but none of them touched the core of my problem.
Reading `man iwconfig` did also not help.
That's why I ask You - Is there any way to print `iwconfig` without `lo` and `eth` interfaces prompting to the console?.

Comment: `ifconfig` gives different information about interfaces, no the the one I'm looking for - unlike `iwconfig`. so it won't do @John

Comment: Sounds like you shoud try `2> /dev/null` instead

Comment: @TomYan this is what I was looking for, thank you. It works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the status of *only* wlan0, use `iwconfig wlan0`. Instead of trying to filter unwanted information, ask the program specifically about information you *do* want.

(If you do not specify an interface name, then your scripts must be prepared for the possibility of there being *two* WEXT interfaces in the system (e.g. one connected from USB) – and once the scripts are prepared to parse multiple interface outputs (separated by blank lines), it really becomes trivial to skip those that have no ESSID information.)

Comment: Thank you for you insight but this does not relate to my question.
I don't won't type `iwconfig wlan<wlan_n0>` only.
My scripts are prepared for extracting information about every `wlan*` based on a separate blank lines.
I shown example of invoking `iwconfig > file_name.txt` and its output : file_name.txt does not contain information about `lo` and `eth0` so I don't need to skip "those line with no ESSID" information.
My question was about unwanted `lo` and `eth` info prompted to the console and @TomYan already gave me an answer.